# Can I set low priority upload request using pycurl/curl to avoid using all upstream

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm building small python application that upload bulk of files to the server using pycurl. Bandwidth throttling is possible using pycurl but that do not solve my problem. I need my app to use 100% upstream when it is available and gracefully downscale it when other application want to use the upstream.

If priority can not be set then I would go for logic where app should consume 70% of total bandwidth.